# Links WSDL: Gravataí

Tags: php, java, wsdl

Seguinte, preciso de links WSDL para Gravataí, já procurei nos manuais e site da prefeitura e do desenvolvedor (IPM) porém só existem links php. Entrei em contato com eles e novamente: Só links php.

Alguém que trabalhe com envio de NFSe para Gravataí e tenha esses links poderia me fornece-los?

O ponto é que eu mantenho um programa em java que faz envio automático de notas e afins, porém ele precisa de links WSDL pra funcionar. Todas as demais cidades usam esse tipo de link pros seus WebServices, como Esteio: "http://grp.esteio.rs.gov.br/nfse/services/NFSEremessa?wsdl".

Caso realmente não existam esses links para Gravataí, como eu utilizo os de PHP dentro do java?